# Get URLs in Stack Overflow queries for posts?

Tags: support

I was recently told about the existence of Stack Exchange Data Explorer through [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293565/am-i-allowed-to-use-robots-to-track-questions). It is great that I can use SQL queries to filter questions. It seems that there isn't any URL field though.

**Have I overlooked it? If not, will the existing fields be enough to concatenate URLs from my computer**, or even SQL itself - in case that SQL concatenation is permitted by the rules?

<sub>I'd like to clarify that I'm not asking for help to build the query. I don't want to waste your time.</sub>

Comment: It's important to note that SEDE is only updated once-a-week (I think on Sundays).  You won't find anything posted today in SEDE until after the next refresh.

Comment: Definetely I will keep researching the best way to use these tools to help the community somemore. This way I won't have to create crawlers for questions, therefore being more gentle with the server's ressources than my first idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SEDE has a few tricks that are hidden in its [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)

One of those is the Magic Columns and Autolinking feature, demonstated in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/310940)

```
select top 100
p.id as [Post Link]
, owneruserid as [User Link]
, creationdate
, tags
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on p.id = pt.postid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = 'c++'
and p.answercount =0
```

The special columnnames like `[Post Link]` will generate links to the post, user or with `[Comment Link]` to a comment.

You might want to read [all material](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) available on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239639/what-sede-examples-would-be-most-useful-to-new-users) first before you enthusiastically fire-off your next question.

Comment: I was willing to research the way to build the query by myself, but I really appreciate the extra effort. Thank you. I also appreciate the MSE material.